# Are there cost differences when running a query using snowpark in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to know if running queries using snowpark from a Jupyter Notebook has a particular toll on cost.

Comment: There is no difference between running a query via Jupyter Notebook compared to running same queries via Snowflake UI as long as you use the same warehouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as @Sergiu mentioned in the comments. Cost is no more/less than using any connector. You will need a virtual warehouse as if the sql generated was in an ordinary worksheet. And you might have to pay a host if your Jupyter notebook is running in the cloud (like JupuyterLabs).
Snowflake doesn't upcharge because the query came from a Snowpark connector.